# Why Does Interaction Plot Show Predicted Values on Y Axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted the following interaction model using `interact_plot` (from the *interactions* package):

```
interact_plot(lin_reg, pred = "insthreat", modx = "affbehav", mod2 = "insbehav",
              y.label = "Quit Intentions")
```

I wanted to see how the three variables interact to predict quit intentions (ranging from 0-7). When I ran the plot, it seemed that the y-axis didn't use the original range (0-7), and instead used a predicted range that went up to 40 (Plot A below).

[image: Plot A]

However, for sake of clarity, I wanted to plot it with a y-axis that only goes up to 7 (the original range). But when I tried to change the y-axis limits, the plot looked completely deformed (Plot B below).

Below was the code I used to change the y-axis:

```
interact_plot(lin_reg, pred = "insthreat", modx = "affbehav", mod2 = "insbehav",
              y.label = "Quit Intentions") + scale_y_continuous(0,7)
```

[image: Plot B]

Why is it that one of the lines disappeared when changing the limits? And does it matter if my interaction plot y-axis far exceeds the range for the outcome variable measure?

Comment: Please include the code you used when you tried to change the y-axis limits (which resulted in your 2nd plot above).

Comment: Sorry about that, just included it!

Comment: Does it work better for you if you use `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 7))` instead?